# Is it correct to use Do just before the verb? In which context we have to use this?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I have observed many sentences like

> Do watch my all episodes

where *do* is used just before a verb. Is it correct to use *do* that way? In what types of sentences we can use this?

Comment: This type of "do" is used for emphasis. It intensifies the ordinary verb. Where "Watch all my episodes" might not seem to be enough, "Do watch all my episodes" makes a special plea concerning the exact same thing. It's more often heard in BrE than AmE, by the way. Which only means that in in AmE it is even *more* emphatic.

Comment: @Robusto, can we use `Do` after `Please`? As : `Please do watch all my episodes` ? It would be better if you answer this question along with some examples.

Comment: Sure. That's fine.

Comment: @Robusto: Curiously though, if I had agreed with OP's request for you to supply a formal Answer, I could reasonably have posted the comment **Please do**. But just **Do** on its own would be  "unidiomatic", to say the least.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't know, I can imagine cases where it might be used naked like that. Q: "Shall I try to avoid bothering you in the future with such small matters?" A: "Do."

Comment: @Robusto, @FumbleFingers, should we take `verb` after `Do` as a `noun` or `verb` or what? For example, in a sentence like: `Do answer this question`, I don't think `answer` plays a role of main `verb`.

Comment: @Robusto: True, we can contrive plausible contexts for almost any sequence of words. But in the vast majority of contexts where **Yes, please do** conveys assent to a suggested action, it would be perfectly ordinary to "reduce" it to any *pair* of those words, or to any *single* word except plain **Do** (where you'd be inclined to append **it** or **so**, for example, because that one word on its own it just doesn't quite stand up).

Comment: @Fumble: Any reply that consists of "Yes, please do" could be reduced to "Yes" or "Please" or "Do," in my estimation.

Comment: related: 1. [When do you use “Did + 1st form” instead of “2nd form”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24237/when-do-you-use-did-1st-form-instead-of-2nd-form) 2. [I know or I do know](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235489/i-know-or-i-do-know) 3. [“did shoot” vs “shot”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot)

Comment: Also related: [What is the difference in meaning between "I play" and "I do play"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-i-play-and-i-do-play)

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to use "Do" in this fashion as an imperative. On its own, though, it tends to feel stiff. Where you will tend to encounter this is in a list of imperatives and it will be written this way to remain somewhat consistent.

> - Do not watch Show X.
> - Do not watch Show Y.
> - Do not watch Movie A.
> - Do not watch Movie B.
> - Do watch Documentary E.
> - Do watch Documentary F.

Comment: Why did you write *show*, *movie* and *documentary* with a capital letter? I don't see any difference between the first two examples except Y is a different letter from X.

Comment: The Monopoly game has the perfect example: *Do not pass Go. Do not collect $200.*

Comment: @PaulRowe, actually I want to know where not to use `Do` before a `main verb`. @Robusto has already given nice comment on what does `Do` mean in such sentences.