# Is the word "do" an adverb or helping verb

Tags: grammar, adverbs

In the sentence "Small children certainly do need careful supervising." Is the word "do" an adverb modifying "need" or is it a helping verb to the main verb "need"?

I'm grading papers and a student classified it as an adverb and it got me wondering whether she wasn't right. She meant it as an adverb using "do" as the opposite of the adverb "not"

Comment: This type of question has been asked several times, but it's damn hard to find one which contains good answers among all the 60,000 questions posted. The answer of the older question actually answers the question title.

Comment: related: [“I know“ or “I do know”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235489/i-know-or-i-do-know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an auxiliary verb added for emphasis. Do find the section treating of auxiliary verbs here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion in English regarding the classification of "do", sometimes, they may be used as a full-verb or as a helping verb, but in this case, **"do" acts as an auxiliary/helping verb**. Here, "certainly" acts as the adverb and provides emphasis to "need".

Answer (score 1):

It's a helping verb, also called an auxiliary.  However, there is an argument for calling it an adverb, as well.  A modifier is something that is Chomsky-adjoined to what it modifies, and the auxiliary "do", if you believe McCawley's description (in **TSPE** and elsewhere) is Chomsky-adjoined to the verb it "helps".

Chomsky-adjunction is a term made up by John Ross to describe the structure of English participles which was proposed by Chomsky in **Aspects of the Theory of Syntax**.  It means that the thing adjoined and what it is adjoined to, make a new constituent of the same category as whatever was adjoined to.   The -ing form of the verb used in the English progressive looks like this:

> He is [V [V eat] ing]

That is, in "He is eating", both "eat" and "eating" count as verbs.  This makes "ing" a modifier of "eat", by the above account of modification.

Now, according to McCawley, auxiliaries have a similar structure, e.g.

> He [V' does [V' eat fish]]

where both "eat fish" and "does eat fish" count as V' (V' are similar to VP, verb phrases).  Compare the structure of a sentence with an adverb which is a V' modifier:

> He [V' always [V' eats fish]]

Same structure, right?  So it appears that "does" is actually an adverb, as well as being an auxiliary verb.

Comment: I'm grading papers and a student classified it as an adverb and it got me wondering whether she wasn't right. She meant it as an adverb using "do" as the opposite of the adverb "not"

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new today.    @user18967 would you mind adding that comment in your question, it explains why you are asking. I thought it was rather odd that you asked if *do* is being used as an adverb. I don't think I have ever heard of it being described as such. It makes the question a bit more interesting, which is never a bad thing.

Comment: ..., but do other adverbs have a plural form like 'do/does'?